# Pikaday keeps reverting time in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, pikaday

I need to setup a datepicker that also allows the user to set a time.
6/6/16 03:28 PM

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(index){
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: $(this)[0],
    position: 'bottom left',
    format: "D/M/YY hh:mm A"
});
});
```

However, while i got the format working, pikaday keeps reverting back to 12:00 AM.

What am i doing wrong? Here's a working example of my issue
https://jsfiddle.net/pturula/hcba6L33/

Comment: I think there should be a selector for hh:mm too, I see only the day selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I understand, *Pikaday* is a **date**picker, not a date&time picker even it returns a standard javascript *Date* object which, in fact, works with complete timestamps.

Dates are simply represented by its timestamp at 0:00h (or 12:00pm).

Because *pikaday* uses standard javascript *Date* object, you can specify any valid formatting string even if it includes time of day parts, but you only can pick for days, so you will always get its 0:00h timestamp.

If you want a date and time picker, then you should search for another imlementation or implement it by yourself (for example by using pikaday and jquery timepicker).

Hope it helps...

**EDIT:** As I said om comments, you can implement it by yourself as two sepparated fields working as single one.

Here the jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/L82h4x1y/

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(index){

    var container = $("<span></span>");
    var dateFld = $("<input type=\"date\"></input>")
        .attr("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy")
        .appendTo(container)
    ;
    var timeFld = $("<input type=\"time\"></input>")
        .attr("placeholder", "h:mm [pm|am]")
        .appendTo(container)
    ;
    var target = $(this)        // Original input field.
        .replaceWith(container) // Replace it in DOM.
        .appendTo(container)    // Reinsert inside new container.
        .hide()                 // Hide it (HINT: comment out me to debug).
    ;

    var picker = new Pikaday({
        field: dateFld[0],
        //format: "D/M/YY hh:mm A"
        format: "D/M/YY"
    });

    function updateFld(){

        // Calculate date part:
        // --------------------
        try {
            var d = new Date(dateFld.val());
            if (isNaN(d)) throw "Wrong date";
        } catch (e) {
            var d = new Date(); // Use current day on invalid values.
        };
        d = d.getDate()
            +"/"+(d.getMonth()+1) // "+1" fixes .getMongh() counting from 0.
            +"/"+d.getFullYear()
        ;

        // Calculate time part:
        // --------------------
        try {
            var t = new Date(
                "2000/1/1 " // Prepend some valid date (notice the ending space).
                +timeFld.val()
            );
            if (isNaN(t)) throw "Wrong time";
        } catch (e) {
            var t = new Date("2000/1/1 0:0"); // Use 0:00 on invalid values
        };
        t = t.getHours() // 0-23
            +":"+t.getMinutes();

        // Update target field:
        // --------------------
        //
        target.val(d+" "+t);
        // NOTE: You will receive 24h date. If you really need "am/pm" you
        // should do a few more plumbing.

    };

    dateFld.on("change", updateFld);
    timeFld.on("change", updateFld);


});
```

**Relevant notes:**

- Notice that extra input fields **does'nt** have any "name" attributes, so the only field which will be send on submit will be the original one.
- Time field accepts am/pm or 24h (any valid javascript *Date* object time) but the original field will be always filled with standard date/time (24h). If it's not what you want, then you well need to do a few more plumbing.
- As said, you can also add a timepicker plugin to the time field (I didn't yet).
- For better testing in jsfiddle, comment out the ".hide()" row of the original field. This way you could see the effect in real time.

Comment: Yes i understand it's a date not date/time picker. I just want to be able to manually edit the date/time chosen without pikaday constantly resetting it.

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand you well then.

But I think you can do something better (and also easier) than that by replacing the original field by a *span* containing the the original field hidden and two additional fields: a datepicker and a timepicker.

Then, the only thing you need to do is capturing the *change* event on both visible fields and calculate the original field value as the concatenation of the relevant parts of both.

It's not hard, but difficult to explain...

Hope I would find time to write some example later...

Comment: I know what you mean bitifet, i suppose i'll need to take that route.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, i see it has a double calendar, but that's a fix i can manage. This is a great solution! Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry! I put «type="date"» unconsciously. It should be «type="text"». Otherwise browsers that support it will trigger its own datepicker.

Answer (score 4):

On their readme page they say:

> Pikaday is a pure datepicker. It will not support picking a time of day. However, there have been efforts to add time support to Pikaday. See [#1](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/1) and [#18](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/18). These reside in their own fork.
>
> You can use the work [@owenmead](https://github.com/owenmead) did most recently at [owenmead/Pikaday](https://github.com/owenmead/Pikaday) A more simple time selection approach done by [@xeeali](https://github.com/xeeali) at [xeeali/Pikaday](https://github.com/xeeali/Pikaday) is based on version 1.2.0. Also [@stas](https://github.com/stas) has a fork [stas/Pikaday](https://github.com/stas/Pikaday), but is now quite old

owenmead's version is still active so I suggest you to use that one. Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcba6L33/2/) example. Because this is a fork and is not as popular as the original it doesn't have cdn, so I copy pasted the minified js and css directly in jsfiddle.

```
// just to bypass "links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code". There is no code change.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/KingRider/hcba6L33/3/

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(index){
        var hour = new Date();
    console.log(hour.get)
    var picker = new Pikaday({
        field: $(this)[0],
        format: "D/M/YY "+hour.getHours()+":"+hour.getMinutes()
    });
});
```

Its? u need time.

Comment: This would have been an awesome fix, however it reverts back to current time. Thanks Though!